# Please help with tag wikis if you have some spare time

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms, tag-wikis

We had an event in the chat last night, and while not many where there, @Roflcopter and myself spent some time updating tag wikis.

We welcome ANYONE with the required reputation levels to [click on tags](https://travel.stackexchange.com/tags), and have a look through and see if they can update some tag information, fix spellings, and suggest synonyms where required.  :)

[image]

touch-ing to re-raise the issue - we have a lot of tags guys!

Comment: @pnuts how can one quickly identify those without a wiki as a list?

Comment: Are there any guidelines for writing tag wikis? Or perhaps a couple of wikis as examples of best practice?

Comment: I did a bit more digging and found https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/ which is somewhat helpful.